# DNS and VPN issues

Tags: apache2, vpn, dns

I recently purchased a year contract for a KVM 512MB VPS running Ubuntu 11.04. I'm having some issues setting up some things on it though - two in particular that I just can't for the life of me figure out.

Okay, so I'm trying to setup pptpd as my VPN for my iPhone and my Mac when I'm out on wireless networks. I'm able to login and the chap authenticates but that's as far as I get, no domains will resolve and end up loading forever, I uncommented ms-dns lines as someone had recommended to me and changed the DNS servers to Googles public ones with no luck, is there something I'm missing? (It's probably staring me in the face.)

My second issue is that I have managed to setup LAMP but am having a problem with my domain, I have pointed the DNS at 123-reg to my VPS's IP and the 'www .' resolves properly, but when I try to go to the domain without the 'www .' I get the apache landing page ("The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.") I'm pretty sure there's something I've gotta configure in Apache for the virtual host but I'm missing it.

Apart from these minor set-backs I'm enjoying the low-level configuration options of having a VPS and love managing my own server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Realise, the fact that whatever you find on a web forum (ask ubuntu) or where ever, may void your contract as such, if the advise is followed and doesn't resolve the issue.

You may also leave yourself with a useless machine.

**IMHO: your first and best bet would contact the vendor for support.**

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the VPN issues, but with the Domain name issue it sounds to me as if the apache setup on the web-server is configured to only recognise the request for the www.domain.com address.

It should be possible to add an 'Alias' line in the Apache config so that it will repond to the domain.com request as well as the www.domain.com request.

The alternative to that is to configure the web server to ONLY respond to the domain.com request (if you can't figure out how to make the apache respond to both request), and change your DNS setup so that the domain.com request is an 'A' record configured with your web-server's IP address, and set the www sub-domain record as a 'CNAME' record configured simply to redirect the request back to 'domain.com'.